# Creating a LIST validation with individual list items

Tags: vba, excel

I need a Worksheet_Change Event to set data validation to certain cells based on a complicated matrix. The data validation should result in cell drop down LIST items!

When you record a macro and you insert the list items separated with semicolons like this "alfa; beta; gamma; delta" the end result will just be fine, in the selected cell each item comes below the previous one.

And you will get the following code (done by Excel VBA):

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="alfa; beta; gamma; delta"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

But when you run the recorded macro in the selected cell you will get ALL ITEMS in one single line `alfa; beta; gamma; delta`

How can I work around this issue?

I need the items being shown one below the next!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA is English orientated, so you will need to use the `,`:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="alfa, beta, gamma, delta"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my afternoon!

Comment: I did already! actually with your help was I able to do so for the first time! B4 I was still a rookie ... ;-)